# Particle>Hair>Collection>Position?

Tags: particles, hair, collections

Hi I'm new to blender so any help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance.
Thanks to this tutorial >> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=35bbyAJodEQ&t=975s

I'm trying to put splash pngs on the ground but I can't find how to fix the position of PNGs
Horizontal black line is the ground and orange rectangles are the splash PNGs.
I want grab those rectangles to the upwards
I've been trying this by Particles>Hair>Collection>Instance Collection

[image]

Comment: Thanks to both of you :) Now it's solved. I'll search up for what else I could do with the "set origin" from now on .. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the object(s) in the collection. Go to edit mode (for each one if you have more objects) select the bottom two vertices, then hit SHIFT + S and choose Cursor to selected. Then go out of edit mode, hit CTRL + SHIFT + ALT + C (yes all at once) and choose origin to 3D cursor. Now the objects should be positioned on top of the plane in your particle system.

Comment: In my experience, the shortcut you mention above hasn't had a function of any kind since the debut of 2.80. In 2.79 it worked as you describe. One must now get the Origin options from the right-click menu.